# InvalidOrMissingInputException when calling follow function

Tags: java, android, getstream-io

When I am trying to do follow action in android, I'm getting below error. Am I missing something?

```
Feed otherTimeline = streamClient.newFeed("Feed", "user1");
otherTimeline.follow("Feed", "user2");
```

Here I want to make user1 to follow the user2

```
InvalidOrMissingInputException{statusCode=400, code=4, exception=InputException, detail=Errors for fields 'target'}
    at io.getstream.client.okhttp.repo.handlers.StreamExceptionHandler.handleResponseCode(StreamExceptionHandler.java:42)
    at io.getstream.client.okhttp.repo.StreamRepositoryImpl.handleResponseCode(StreamRepositoryImpl.java:223)
    at io.getstream.client.okhttp.repo.StreamRepositoryImpl.fireAndForget(StreamRepositoryImpl.java:219)
    at io.getstream.client.okhttp.repo.StreamRepositoryImpl.follow(StreamRepositoryImpl.java:101)
    at io.getstream.client.model.feeds.BaseFeed.follow(BaseFeed.java:53)
    at com.ibtspl.startup.fragment.StreamChatFragment$FollowFeed.doInBackground(StreamChatFragment.java:112)
    at com.ibtspl.startup.fragment.StreamChatFragment$FollowFeed.doInBackground(StreamChatFragment.java:106)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregated feeds can't be followed. Only flat feeds are the ones that can be followed in getstream.io see this [documentation](https://getstream.io/docs/java/#flat-feeds)